# Using Viewer3D methods inside an Aggregated Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to build functionality for selected objects and shown models in my Aggregated View.
I can't seem to figure out how to use the "getSelection" method that is available to the Viewer3D (which Aggregated View is built on?). I can **getModel** easy enough though:

```
function extGetModels() {
var modelurn = [];
var visibleModels = viewer.getVisibleNodes();
visibleModels.forEach(model => {
    var i = viewer.getModel(model);
    modelurn.push(i);
});
```

Is there any examples how I can use the methods in Viewer3D in my aggregated view?

(sorry if this question seems banal, I'm quite new to JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite straightforward, just use `AggregatedView.viewer`. For example,

```js
const view = new Autodesk.Viewing.AggregatedView();
view.init( viewerDiv, options3d );


// somewhere in your code ...

const viewer = view.viewer;
viewer.getVisibleNodes();
```

Ref: https://gist.github.com/yiskang/c404af571ba4d631b5929c777503891e#file-index-html-L81